# Can I add any indicator to any chart type in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I normally saw in highcahrts API example that indicators like **Linear, SMA, EMA, MACD** was drawn in **line** chart type. can it be drawn in **ohlc** and **candlestick** also?

Answer (score 2):

I advice to familiar with the indicators plugin:

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/24/Indicators/

Comment: is that support MACD? because i didn't find MACD there.

Comment: can I add indicators by using addseries() function?

Comment: Do you mean addseries with indicator or only indicator?

Comment: Yes you can add a new serie, but you need to prepare your own algothiem which will calculate MACD values and push to the serie.